# Adding a public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys does not log me in automatically

Tags: ssh, public-key, authorized-keys

I added the public SSH key to the *authorized_keys* file.  `ssh localhost` should log me in without asking for the password.

I did that and tried typing `ssh localhost`, but it still asks me to type in the password. Is there another setting that I have to go through to make it work?

I have followed the instructions for changing permissions:

Below is the result if I do `ssh -v localhost`.

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/john/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/identity type 1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/john/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/john/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/john/.ssh/identity
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
```

Then it asks for a passphase after the above log. Why isn't it logging me in without a password?

Comment: While it isn't the case here, if you're coming from Google and you're using an encrypted home directory, sshd won't be able to access it, and therefore won't be able to read your authorized_keys file. Here's a solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/362427/comments/12

Answer (score 1268, accepted):

You need to verify the permissions of the `authorized_keys` file and the folder / parent folders in which it is located.

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

For more information see [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140327182105/http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14).

You may also need to change/verify the permissions of your home directory to remove write access for the group and others.

```
chmod go-w ~
```

Comment: Well something in the above worked, though isn't "chmod -R go-wrx foobar" rather dramatic? Why the need for recursive?

Comment: For the second part, it's not neccesary to make it recursive, just doing the `chmod go-wrx foobar` is enough. Doing it recursively could seriously bone some applications if you have some group or other access to files, especially if it's a web directory.

Comment: As mentioned on the OpenSSH FAQ, the user's home & .ssh directory only needs to write permission removed for group/other (so ``chmod go-w $HOME $HOME/.ssh`` will do the trick).  Thus, permissions can be as 'open' as 755 for both directories, if you're so inclined.  The simplest/least invasive commands are in the FAQ: http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14

Comment: Why would didn't it work for me until I did `chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`?  600 didn't work where 644 did...

Comment: I noticed that this did not work on a windows PC with Cygwin because when I issue `chmod 0600 .ssh/id_rsa*`, the command goes, but for some reason Windows doesn't allow it, and my question about this got removed for some reason else where on the site about this.

Comment: @Pred I don't know about Cygwin.

Comment: @Teddy I don't remember where I found it, but I had to change ownership of the folder .ssh in Cygwin to be owned by Users, then I could chmod 0600

Comment: If anything, this made it worse... I got the error `Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.` until I restored the original permissions (`664`)

Comment: Correct permissions may not be enough when SELinux is enforced. You might need to run `sudo restorecon -FRvv ~username/.ssh`

Comment: Also note that I had to do this both on the client side running ssh program and server side running sshd program. Not either, but rather both.

Comment: FYI, I created a small script at https://github.com/centic9/generate-and-send-ssh-key which runs the necessary steps in one go and additionally ensures all the file/directory permissions which always caused me headaches...

Comment: I also needed to `sudo chown -R {$USER}:{$USER} ~/.ssh/` because I had written the `authorized_keys` file as root.

Comment: If you happen to have a non-standard private key file name (e.g. anything other than `id_rsa`, `id_dsa`, or `id_ecdsa`), you may need to provide the `-i path-to-private-key-file` to your `ssh` command.

Comment: Sonofab... the chmod on the home directory was it for me. Who would have thought of that? Grr.. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: wow...in my case the permissions of the complete /home/user directory was set to 777...(wtf)...I had to remove write permissions for group and all - now it works like a charme, thanks :)

Comment: @ficuscr - or others wondering why permissions 644 worked when 600 didn't... ssh tunneling requests *may* require that file to have 644 specifically. I've always connected ok with 600 with ssh keys with basic terminal connection to my server. But for fancier applications, port-forwarding, ProxyCommand, etc. you may need group or world read permissions on the file, or the remote file... or ... as needed.

Answer (score 170):

[SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) can also cause authorized_keys not to work. Especially for root in [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6 and 7. There isn't any need to disable it though.

Once you've verified your permissions are correct, you can fix this like so:

```
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh
```

Comment: The `restorecon` is what you need after you have copied the files by hand, e.g. to a new hard drive. (You should probably run it on all files in this case. Could fix other odd problems.)

Comment: Another happy camper here. This was my problem in RHEL 6.5

Comment: 9/10 times, a "why isn't this working, it always works" issue is an selinux issue.

Comment: fixed the problem for me on 1and1 (1und1) server

Comment: Fixed for me on fedora 35 when migrating home to another hdd

Answer (score 123):

Setting **ssh authorized_keys** seem to be simple, but it hides some traps I'm trying to figure.

-- SERVER --

In **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**, set `passwordAuthentication yes` to let the server temporarily accept password authentication

-- CLIENT --

> consider [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) as Linux emulation and install & run OpenSSH

**1.** Generate private and public keys (client side)
`# ssh-keygen`

Here pressing just <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you get *default* two files, "**id_rsa**" and "**id_rsa.pub**", in **~/.ssh/**, but if you give a **name_for_the_key**, the generated files are saved in your **current working directory**.

**2.** Transfer the **your_key.pub** file to the target machine, `ssh-copy-id user_name@host_name`

If you didn't create a default key, this is the first step to go wrong
... you should use:

`ssh-copy-id -i path/to/key_name.pub user_name@host_name`

**3.** Logging `ssh user_name@host_name` will work only for the default *id_rsa* file, so here is the second trap. You need to do `ssh -i path/to/key_name user@host`

(Use **ssh -v ...** option to see what is happening.)

If **the server still asks for a password** then you gave something. To **Enter passphrase:** when you've  created keys (so it's normal).

If ssh is not listening on the default port 22, you must use `ssh -p port_nr`.

-- SERVER -----

**4.** Modify file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** to have

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(uncomment if case)

This tells ssh to accept file *authorized_keys* and look in the user home directory for the *key_name* sting written in the *.ssh/authorized_keys* file.

**5** Set permissions on the target machine

```
chmod 755 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also turn off pass authentication,

`passwordAuthentication no`

to close the gate to all ssh root/admin/....@your_domain attempts.

**6.** Ensure ownership and group ownership of all non-root home directories are appropriate.

```
chown -R ~ usernamehere
chgrp -R ~/.ssh/ user
```

===============================================

**7.** Consider the excellent http://www.fail2ban.org

**8.** Extra
[SSH *tunnel*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40619202/953374) to access a MySQL (bind = 127.0.0.1) server

Comment: Note that "just 4 security" is not just for security! SSH will ignore the file if it does not have restrictive permissions.

Comment: Ensuring ownership would be a great addition to this list

Comment: I had no idea about `ssh-copy-id`! That step alone would make a great answer.

Comment: chmod 755 ~/.ssh instead of 700 that I see elsewhere seemed to do it

Comment: WOW... my issue was the "default naming" (Step 2). SSH does not pickup any files in ".ssh" ? this  cost me some days... Thanks a lot!

Comment: `AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`
This line is important. Especially if you have managed to do something clever like tell it to ignore a user's authorized keys file for security.

Answer (score 41):

Also be sure your home directory is not writeable by others:

```
chmod g-w,o-w /home/USERNAME
```

This answer is stolen from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder/527397#527397?newreg=aaa3c1de0863490a8139c8a4363c07bd#answer-527397).

Comment: Doing
`chmod 700 ~/.ssh ;
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ; 
chmod g-w,o-w ~`
worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: why not use just `chmod og-w /home/USERNAME` instead?

Answer (score 16):

The desperate may also make sure they don't have extra newlines in the *authorized_keys* file due to copying file *id_rsa.pub*'s text out of a confused terminal.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me! the two terminals are same width so it's hard to figure out until I turned on the line numbers to see two lines in the authorized_keys file.

Comment: This. I just wasted an hour because of this. And it's not the first time. @bortunac's answer mentions the ssh-copy-id tool, which I will use in the future to avoid this.

Comment: I got the contents of `id_rsa.pub` using `more` instead of `cat`, which was fatal because of the invisible linebreaks.

Answer (score 8):

Listing a public key in *.ssh/authorized_keys* is necessary, but not sufficient for sshd (server) to accept it. If your private key is passphrase-protected, you'll need to give ssh (client) the passphrase every time. Or you can use *[ssh-agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent)*, or a GNOME equivalent.

Your *updated* trace is consistent with a passphrase-protected private key. See ssh-agent, or use `ssh-keygen -p`.

Answer (score 8):

In the following, *user* is your username.

```
mkdir -p /home/user/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
touch /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
touch /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts
chown -R user:user /home/user/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/id*
chmod 644 /home/user/.ssh/id*.pub
chmod 644 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 644 /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Better for root:
`mkdir -p /home/$USER/.ssh &&
chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.ssh &&
sudo -u $USER ssh-keygen -t rsa  &&
touch /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys  &&
touch /home/$USER/.ssh/known_hosts  &&
chmod 700 /home/$USER/.ssh &&
chmod 600 /home/$USER/.ssh/id* &&
chmod 644 /home/$USER/.ssh/id*.pub &&
chmod 644 /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys &&
chmod 644 /home/$USER/.ssh/known_hosts &&
vim /home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys # paste keys here!`

Answer (score 7):

Beware that [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) can trigger this error as well, even if all permissions seem to be OK. Disabling it did the trick for me (insert usual disclaimers about disabling it).

Comment: You can see SELinux interfering in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.  `restorecon -R -v /root/.ssh` fixed my specific case.

Answer (score 6):

Look in file `/var/log/auth.log` on the server for `sshd` authentication errors.

If all else fails, then run the `sshd` server in debug mode:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p 2200
```

Then connect from the client:

```
ssh user@host -p 2200
```

In my case, I found the error section at the end:

```
    debug1: userauth_pubkey: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable for RSA SHA256:6bL+waAtghY5BOaY9i+pIX9wHJHvY4r/mOh2YaL9RvQ [preauth]
==> debug2: userauth_pubkey: disabled because of invalid user [preauth]
    debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
    debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]
    debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
    debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
```

With this information I realized that my `sshd_config` file was restricting logins to members of the `ssh` group. The following command fixed this permission error:

```
sudo usermod -a -G ssh NEW_USER
```

Comment: This extra logging is very useful, thanks!  It showed me that one of my keys -- copied and pasted into authorized_keys -- had a line break in the middle of it!

Answer (score 5):

Try "ssh-add" which worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

The thing that did the trick for me finally was to make sure that the **owner/group** were not *root*, but *user*:

```
chown -R ~/.ssh/ user
chgrp -R ~/.ssh/ user
```

Comment: chown: invalid user: ‘/home/lsa/.ssh/’

Comment: @Stepan Yakovenko: "user" is not literal(?). An improved answer could make this more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Issue these on the command line:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

After you do this, make sure your directory is like this:

```
drwx------ 2 lab lab 4.0K Mar 13 08:33 .
drwx------ 8 lab lab 4.0K Mar 13 08:07 ..
-rw------- 1 lab lab  436 Mar 13 08:33 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 lab lab 1.7K Mar 13 07:35 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 lab lab  413 Mar 13 07:35 id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: how your answer is different with accepted one? You've wrote it 3 years later using your Ctrl+C Ctrl-V command?

Answer (score 3):

Another tip to remember: Since v7.0 [OpenSSH disables DSS/DSA SSH keys by default](https://www.gentoo.org/support/news-items/2015-08-13-openssh-weak-keys.html) due to their inherit weakness. So if you have OpenSSH v7.0+, make sure your key is not `ssh-dss`.

> If you are stuck with DSA keys, you can re-enable support locally by
> updating your `sshd_config` and `~/.ssh/config` files with lines like so: `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss`

Answer (score 3):

Another issue you have to take care of: If your generated file names are not the default `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`.

You have to create the *.ssh/config* file and define manually which *id* file you are going to use with the connection.

An example is here:

```
Host remote_host_name
    HostName 172.xx.xx.xx
    User my_user
    IdentityFile /home/my_user/.ssh/my_user_custom
```

Comment: The IdentityFile should be the private key

Comment: @KenH yeah sure. typo it is. sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I needed to put my `authorized_keys` file in `.openssh`.

This location is specified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` under the option `AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: There's a whole class of problems that can occur on the server (when trying to connect from a client) that are impossible to debug without access to the server... This is by design to hide info from malicious clients, but makes it harder to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the target user has a password set. Run `passwd username` to set one. This was required for me even if password SSH login was disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Just look in file **/var/log/auth.log** on the **server**. Setting additional verbosity with **-vv** on the client side won't help, because the server is unlikely to offer too much information to a possible attacker.

Answer (score 1):

I issued `sudo chmod 700 ~/.ssh` and `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `chmod go-w $HOME $HOME/.ssh` from a previous answer and it fixed my problem on a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7 box that I had messed up the permissions on while trying to get [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) shares working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a permission problem. Usually it happens if the permission of some file/directory is not correctly set up. In most case they are `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/*`. In my case they are `/home/xxx`.

You can change the log level of *sshd* by modifying file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`(search for `LogLevel`, and set it to `DEBUG`) and then check the output in file `/var/log/auth.log` to see what happened exactly.

Comment: This looks substantially identical to the accepted answer and should probably have been a comment on it, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, please do not use answers as a workaround.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's the way to solve all kinds of this question. Now I know how to do it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solves my problem:

```
ssh-agent bash

ssh-add
```

Comment: Explain what that does, please.

Comment: The ssh-agent stores your ssh keys..the command bash starts a new instance of its shell. and ssh-add unlocks your keys and loads them

Answer (score 1):

In my case it's because the user's group is not set in AllowGroups of configuration file */etc/ssh/sshd_config*. After adding it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a modified AuthorizedKeysFile, when the automation to populate /etc/ssh/authorized_keys had not yet been run.

```
$sudo grep AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  /etc/ssh/authorized_keys/%u
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've copied the whole public key to `authorized_keys`; the `ssh rsa` prefix is necessary for the key to work.

Comment: used ssh-copy-id

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify the properties of the files.

To assign the required property, use:

```
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/sshKey
$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/sshKey.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

After setting the correct permissions, ssh still wouldn't log me in without the password.

So, after combing through the `/var/log/auth.log` I saw

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /root
```

In addition to setting permissions, ownership needed to be set. On server side, do

```
chown root /root
chown root /root/.ssh
```

and then

```
chmod go-w ~/ 
chmod 700 ~/.ssh 
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Credit: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548327/authentication-refused-bad-ownership-or-modes-for-directory-root).

Answer (score 0):

On that note, make sure your *sshd* configuration has this line:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Set as the above, and then restart *sshd* (`/etc/init.d/sshd restart`).

Log out and try log in in again!

The default, I believe, is:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the home directory in a non-standard location and in `sshd` logs I have the following line, even if all permissions were just fine (see the other answers):

> Could not open authorized keys '/data/home/user1/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied

I have found a solution here: *[Trouble with ssh public key authentication to RHEL 6.5](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=25813191&sid=0876f069ec2aa5fdcd691a2e2e7242c2#p25813191)*

In my particular case:

- Added a new line in `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs`:
- This is the original line for regular home directories:

  `/home/[^/]*/\.ssh(/.*)? unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0`
- This is my new line:

  `/data/home/[^/]*/\.ssh(/.*)? unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0`
- Followed by a `restorecon -r /data/` and a `sshd` restart.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and none of the other answers solved it, although of course the other answers *were* correct.

In my case, it turned out that the `/root` directory itself (not e.g. `/root/.ssh`) had the wrong permissions. I needed:

```
chown root.root /root
chmod 700 /root
```

Of course, those permissions should be something like that (maybe `chmod 770`) regardless. However, it specifically prevented `sshd` from working, even though `/root/.ssh` and `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` both had correct permissions and owners.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I added the group of the login user to another user.

Let's say there is an SSH-login user called userA and a non-SSH-login user userB. userA has the group userA as well. I modified userB to have the group userA as well. The lead to the the described behaviour, so that userA was not able to login without a prompt.

After I removed the group userA from userB, the login without a prompt worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I use it this way.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub| ssh user@remote-system 'umask 077; cat >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issues since before, but today I had to set up one new server. What I could learn in this time...

The basic process to allow authentication without a password is as follows:

1. **On the server**, validate if your home folder has the `.ssh` folder. If it doesn't exist, you can create it manually with a `mkdir` command and then to assign the correct permissions with `chmod`, or otherwise you could use the same utility, `ssh-keygen`, to create private/public keys, but on the server for your user. This process will create the required `.ssh` folder.
2. **On the local machine** you also need to create the private/public keys with the `ssh-keygen` utility.
3. You need to move your public key to file `.ssh/authorized_keys` to the server. To achieve this, you can use the `ssh-copy-id` utility, or you can do it manually using the `cat` and `scp` commands.
4. In the best of cases, this will allow connect to your server without a password.

OK, now the issues that I found today: first there are several key generation algorithms: `rsa`, `dsa`, `ecdsa` and `ed25519` and there are many releases of OpenSSH (you can have one version on your local machine and an old version on your server):

**Hint:** Using `ssh -v` helps to see additional information when you are connecting to the server.

`OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`

`debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3`

The error in my case today was that I was trying to use a key with a "newer" generation algorithm that was not supported by the installed version of OpenSSH on the server. When I had checked the supported algorithms, another error that I found was that the server was rejecting my algorithm:

`debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`

After that, I had to change the algorithm of my key and then I could connect with the server successfully.

OpenSSH releases notes: [Link](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html)

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, we'll move the root key to the example_user, which also
> disables the root user's SSH key access.
>
> 1. SSH to the instance as root.
> 2. Create the `.ssh` directory for example_user.
>
>    `# mkdir /home/example_user/.ssh`
> 3. Move the root key to example_user's SSH directory.
>
>    `# mv /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/example_user/.ssh/`
> 4. Change the ownership of the `.ssh` directory from root to example_user so OpenSSH can read it.
>
>    `# chown -R example_user:example_user /home/example_user/.ssh`

Source - https://www.vultr.com/docs/using-your-ssh-key-to-login-to-non-root-users#Option_2__Move_the_root_SSH_Key_to_the_Non_root_User