# MySQL connection over SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have set up a SSH tunnel between two servers **A** and **B**. **B** has MySQL server, and this works:

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u user -p
```

While this doesn't:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u user -p
```

Although my.cnf has these lines:

```
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
# Next addr differs slightly, but anyway
bind-address        = 99.99.99.99
```

Now about the tunnel. It connects the following:`(A) localhost(9989) -> (B) localhost(3306)`
But when (on **A**,  with ports forwarded) I do

```
mysql -v -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9989 -u user userdb -p
```

I get `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

And when I do

```
mysql -v -h localhost -P 9989 -u user userdb -p
```

I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

What might be the reason? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are three issues here.

1 - Forget about the SSH tunnel for now

You cannot bind MySQL to more than one specific IP.
The first `bind-address` clause is overridden (therefore, ignored) by the second one. Your server only listens to `99.99.99.99`.

The reason why you can connect with `-h localhost` but not with `-h 127.0.0.1` is that in the first form, you do not actually connect through TCP/IP, but through a local socket.

Look in your `my.cnf` for a `socket` clause.

Remove one redundant `bind-address` clause. You may want to use `bind-address=0.0.0.0`, which instructs MySQL daemon to listen to *all* network interfaces.

2 - Let's setup your SSH tunnel

The reason for you error `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0` is not obvious to me. I *suspect* SSH tunnel is actually established only when it receives a connection request (in your case, when you run the `mysql` client). Since your server does not listen to 127.0.0.1 (see previous paragraph), the SSH tunnel cannot be established, connection fails, and your client interprets it as a network failure.

3 - Why `mysql -v -h localhost -P 9989 -u user userdb -p` fails

Please post the output of

*[edit : just added `...OR host LIKE 'localhost'` below, as this might be relevant for troubleshooting purposes]*

```
mysql > SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user LIKE 'user' OR host LIKE 'localhost';
```

(replace `'user'`, after the `LIKE` clause, with the actual user name if necessary)

MySQL access control checks both the username/password (`user`) and the origin of the connection (`host`) to identify a user. You probably did not create a user `'user'@'localhost'`.

N.B.: mysql.com being unreachable from my location at this time, I cannot link to the relevant manual pages.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Fixing the first issue made it work.

Comment: You may have missed my last edit: "You may want to use `bind-address=0.0.0.0`, which instructs MySQL daemon to listen to all network interfaces.". You are most welcome.

Comment: What's the difference between localhost, 127.0.0.1, and a local socket?

Comment: Local Sockets (a.k.a Unix Domain Sockets http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) are one of the many possibilities for IPC (Inter-Process Communication - communication paths between two processes running on the same machine). It is comparable to shared memory. With `mysql -hlocalhost`, the client uses the socket. `mysql -h127.0.0.1` explicitely instructs the client to use TCP/IP. Local Socket are more efficient because they bypass the network layer.

Comment: Saved me with the bind-address fix!

Comment: Ironically, this answer helped me with something completely unrelated. I couldn't get Propel to generate from a database through an SSH tunnel, so I set the host from localhost to 0.0.0.0 and it worked.

Comment: Nice explanation

Comment: This is a great answer and it helped me to discover a common error by referencing the wrong port.  In my case I was mistakenly referring to the RDP port 3389:

ssh -p222 -L 10000:192.168.0.1:3389 user@server

instead of the MySQL port 3306:

ssh -p222 -L 10000:192.168.0.1:3306 user@server

It is my understanding that the reference to the local port number of 10000 is largely irrelevant, but you will want to choose a port number that is high enough that it is not going to conflict with another existing port.

Answer (score 11):

I just encountered this very problem.

In my case MySQL server is configured with `bind-address: 192.168.4.4`.
I originally setup an SSH tunnel with a commonly mentioned `-L 3306:localhost:3306 user@server` string and from my computer connect with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1`.

This does not work because MySQL no longer listens on *0.0.0.0* or even `"localhost"`(aka 127.0.0.1), only `192.168.4.4`.

The correct tunnel string should be `-L 3306:192.168.4.4:3306 user@server`.
This will tell the remote tunnel end to connect to MySQL using the IP MySQL actually listens on.

Answer (score 11):

STEP-BY-STEP SSH TUNNELING

--- SERVER SIDE ----

in target machine (that can be addresed by IP  or a domain hosted)  there is config file **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** having a line

```
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
```

confirmed with console

```
netstat -tapn |  grep mysql
// tcp    0    0 127.0.0.1:3306     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      18469/mysqld
```

which means mysql server will respond only to request from the localhost

--- CLIENT SIDE ----

you have an account (eventualy a ssh-key) to log  using cygwin,putty or a linux_shell

```
ssh user_name@host_name
```

create SSH TUNNEL

```
ssh -f -N -L 1000:127.0.0.1:3306    user_name@host_name
```

which means  hey ssh create a permanent connection from port 1000 on the machine that I type  (client) to remote  host_name:3306  ....  127.0.0.1 means here the remote (host_name) and should not be replaced with localhost word because this will make the connection on unix (named) socket not by IP  ...  You'll get *'ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql.sock' (2)'* when trying co connect mysql

-f = go in background
-N = no excution

both -f -N kind of nohoop - you can close console and tunnels persist

--- SERVER SIDE ---

```
netstat -tapn |  grep ssh
// tcp  0  0  server_ip:22   clint_ip:port  ESTABLISHED 24915/sshd: user_name
```

which means there is a permanent connection through shh protocol

--- CLIENT SIDE ---

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 1000 -u mysql_user -pmysql_pass
```

now your (client side) mysql client is conected to remote mysql server ... here 127.0.0.1 is client machine

same for workbench, heidiSQL

---

how to kill ssh tunnels

```
ps fax | grep ssh
kill process_id
```

Comment: nice clear explanation. I was using the host_name instead of 127.0.0.1 in my ssh tunnelling command. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In my case, a configuration in the SSH daemon was blocking the tunnel. AllowTcpForwarding should be enabled.

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Answer (score 1):

I did have the same proble (`"Lost connection..."`) on Windows (while using ssh tunnel via Putty). I got 2 issues here:

1. Wrong port was used, double check if you are setting it correctly
2. I forgot enabling in `Putty: Connection > SSH > Tunnels > Local ports accept connections from other hosts`

Answer (score 0):

A simple step worked for me... I'll share this, so maybe some of you can be spared a headache.

MY SETTING

In my particular case, I have a Percona server running on Ubuntu, connected to MySQL Workbench (in a Windows VM) through SSH; the server ran fine for several days before spitting an error 10060 while processing a query.

WHAT WORKED FOR ME

I found in a forum from Acquia.com that in some cases the Workbench won't accept '127.0.0.1' as host, so you must change it to 'localhost'. I did it, and it worked (oddly, the Workbench asked for the passwords again, even if they were already stored, but worked nevertheless).