# Using Flyway with a ssh tunnel to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, maven, flyway

I'm try to use the Flyway db configuration management tool with MySQL databases that are only accessible via an ssh tunnel.   I can't seem to find any mention on how to do this in the Flyway docs...not sure if that is because it is utterly obvious, or because it can't be done? BTW, at the moment I'm trying to do this with the flyway maven plugin (since most of our CI environment revolves around maven).

FWIW, if I manually set up an ssh tunnel, I can do the rest of the Flyway migration in maven...so maybe the question is how to have maven set up an ssh tunnel on it's own.   There seems to be that capability for deployments, but I've been unable to discover how to do it for a general case.   Heck, I'm not all that wedded to maven -- if this would be a slam-dunk in some other tool (say, gradle), then I'm willing to go down that road.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Flyway problem per se. Have a look here for how to set a MySQL connection up through an SSH tunnel: [MySQL connection over SSH tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061621/mysql-connection-over-ssh-tunnel?rq=1)