# How do I reverse engineer over an SSH tunnel with Propel?

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I can only connect to my database through an SSH tunnel. Up until now, I've been dumping the schema from my database and loading it onto my local. How can I connect directly to my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is entirely lacking on the internet, so I'm answering my own question.

1. Shut down your local MySQL server instance (if you have one).
2. Open a terminal and run the following command:

   ```
   ssh -L 3307:[database hostname]:3306 [SSH username]@[SSH hostname] [-p[SSH port]]
   ```

   This might also work with PuTTY, I'm not sure.
3. In your build.properties, set the following:

   ```
   propel.database.url=mysql:host=0.0.0.0;port=3307;dbname=[database name]
   ```

It **cannot** be localhost. If it is, you will receive the following error:

```
propel > reverse:

     [echo] +-----------------------------------------------+
     [echo] |                                               |
     [echo] | Generating XML from PDO connection !          |
     [echo] |                                               |
     [echo] +-----------------------------------------------+
[propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata: vendor/propel/propel1/generator/build-propel.xml:296:1: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 0.2293 seconds
```

This cryptic error means that it cannot find the Unix socket on your computer because, [even if you are specifying the host and the port](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php), PDO will still look for one with `localhost`. Obviously, you can never open a socket for a server that does not reside on your machine, and even if you add `unix_socket` to the DSN as null, it will complain about being a bad filename. Using `0.0.0.0` fixes this error. I actually figured that out from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11062068/904344).

And you're done! You can now reverse engineer with Propel over an SSH tunnel.