# Can I change MySQL Workbench's default "mysql" execution command?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**Question**

My assumption is MySQL Workbench runs this:

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u user -p
```

How can I make it run this?:

```
mysqle -h localhost -P 3306 -u user -p
```

**Reason**

I am working with a client who runs two instances of MySQL on one server. The command `mysql` does not launch MySQL as it normally does. Rather, they use `mysqle` and `mysqlw`. I *believe* this is the cause of a MySQL Workbench error when attempting to connect with Standard TCP/IP over SSH:

> Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication
>   packet', system error: 0

This error has been [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061621/mysql-connection-over-ssh-tunnel), but I believe is unrelated.

Comment: I doubt it runs any `mysql` command, it presumably uses an API to connect to the database.

Comment: Workbench is a program with a compiled in mysql library. Perhaps you are referring to 2 batch / shell scripts of theirs

Comment: That could be. If that's the case, do you know if it's possible to edit those scripts?

Comment: vim to the rescue. Find the .bat or .sh files . I see no reason why a machine could not run fine with Workbench while not even having the mysql client tools installed.

Comment: I didn't have much luck. I did find a couple .sh files, but nothing indicated that's where the actual "mysql" command executes. Now I'm trying to just make mysql execute the mysqle command through path or alias, etc..