# ssh connection using cygwin

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I am trying to connect with my remote linux server using cygwin+ssh but the authentication fails with no apparent reason. I have successfully setup another connnection to github successfully and I have followed the same process, this is why I am stopped here

```
$ ssh -v finxxx@xxx.79.xxx.29
OpenSSH_6.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Connecting to xxx.79.xxx.29 [xxx.79.xxx.29] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA c7:b2:f1:f9:76:cd:24:5a:80:91:4b:e5:ac:7e:e1:ee
debug1: Host 'xxx.79.xxx.29' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxxtta/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have made the standard stuff but I cannot solve the problem. These are the commands I have used to generate the private/public keys. I have then copied the public key to the server

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_dsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_dsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/xxxtta/.ssh/id_dsa.pub
```

thank you for your help

**EDIT:**
I have made the same procedure using MINGW and it works (I am able to connect). Something is definitely going wrong with cygwin in my system

Comment: Did you add your id_dsa.pub to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, I have copied the public key on the remote server under authorized_keys

Comment: I know it's been years, but it would be interesting to know what the solution was in your specific case!

Answer (score 2):

Problem probably lies in user name. If you login remotely user name is case sensitive. You must write user name exactly how it was defined in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Copy id_dsa.pub to your remote server.

```
# scp .ssh/id_dsa.pub dude@remotemachine
```

On remote server:

```
# cat id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: yes, I have copied the key :/ I have made the complete steps several times before that, I am not completely new to that process

Answer (score 0):

You might try -vvv instead of -v to increase the verbosity.
Also, check that the file permissions are set properly.  See [Adding public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys does not log me in automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically)