# SSH - Entering a Passphrase Only Once

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, zsh, ssh-agent

On `$ ssh localhost`, I was being asked to provide **password**. It was tedious and kind of annoying to provide **password** for every login.

So, I have created ssh keys with passphrase..

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I have copied the content of the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now, on `$ ssh localhost` I was being asked to provide **passphrase**. No improvement, but instead of providing **password** I was providing **passphrase**.

I came across [Adding public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys does not log me in automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically), but it did not address my problem.
As [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically#comment-11836851) states, that if the the keys were created with a passphrase, it will always ask for passphrase.

However, if the the **ssh keys** would have been created **without passphrase**, passphrase would not be required for any `ssh` operation.

The key take away from this post was the verbose flag `-v` and

```
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
```

On searching about `PEM_read_PrivateKey failed` I came across quite a number of posts, couple of them are from stackoverflow itself.

But could not find a proper solution.

Then I came across [Setting up passwordless, passphraseless ssh](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/ssh-keys.html) which states about using a ssh agent to enter the passphrase automatically.

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

or

```
$ eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

but again, it solved only for that specific session. Every time I start a new session I have to execute the

```
$ eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I could add it to my .bashrc or .zshrc but it's annoying to enter the passphrase for every session.

**Is there any way to use the same ssh-agent across session?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve the cross session `ssh-agent`, one has to comprehend

```
$ eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

On executing, `ssh-agent`, it will output few **unix command** to the `STDOUT`

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-qtCEoF3298/agent.3298; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=3299; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 3299;
```

**evaluating** or `eval`-ing a `command` will execute the **command's output**.

So, `` eval`ssh-agent` `` would translate to

```
$ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-qtCEoF3298/agent.3298; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK; SSH_AGENT_PID=3299; export SSH_AGENT_PID; echo Agent pid 3299;
```

The above statements sets the environment variables **SSH_AUTH_SOCK** and **SSH_AGENT_PID** and also prints the **agent's process id** to the `STDOUT`

The environment variable **SSH_AUTH_SOCK points to a UNIX socket**.

```
$ file $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-qtCEoF3298/agent.3298: socket
```

For any other `ssh` operation, it looks for this socket, if present it uses it or ask for the passphrase. But this socket needs to be **authenticated**, prior it can be used. And that is done by adding the identity

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**Since the environment variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK is exported, it is available for any shell originating from this shell, but not any new login**.

Then I came across [Understanding ssh-agent and ssh-add](http://joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/) which guided to [ssh-find-agent.bash](https://github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent/blob/master/ssh-find-agent.bash)

[ssh-find-agent.bash](https://github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent/blob/master/ssh-find-agent.bash) looks for all live agent socket and exports them as environment variable.

**As suggested by [Jon Cairns](http://joncairns.com/), in the post.**

> > Download it somewhere accessible (e.g. ~/.ssh-find-agent) and add the following to your shell's configuration file (e.g. ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc):***
> >
> > `source ~/.ssh-find-agent/ssh-find-agent.bash`
> >
> > `set_ssh_agent_socket`

**AND THIS IS THE SOLUTION I HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR**

I have modified the function names, to suit my preference, same can be found at [ssh-auth-sock](https://github.com/sarbbottam/conf-files/blob/master/dot-commons/ssh-auth-sock)
The functions related to `GPG`, `GNOME` & `OSX` are not required for my purpose. The script needs to be refactored.

Moreover, `OS X` has its own keychain.
[Thus I execute these functions only for `Linux`](https://github.com/sarbbottam/conf-files/blob/master/dot-files/dot-common#L10-L15)

I have also created an [alias for eval `ssh-agent` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa](https://github.com/sarbbottam/conf-files/blob/master/dot-commons/aliases#L31) , which is **quicker** to type than the whole command.