# how to give a username and a password via a git push

Tags: git, push, credentials

I'm trying to use a username and a password for a git push but I cannot find the options to use with the git command.

I've tried: http://username@gitserver/project

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push : username , password, how to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/git-push-username-password-how-to-avoid)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git Push Error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you don't provide the credentials in the URL. It's OK to have the username in there like you did - Git will then ask for the password.

You could try adding the password like this, but it's not a good idea, since it means having the password in plain text, issues with special characters/encoding, etc.:

http://username:password@gitserver/project

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but in general, it's better to use a *credential helper* to store passwords so you don't have to reenter them every time: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git - this page has instructions for the most common operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Git leaves authentication to the used protocol, like `ssh` or `http` in your case, therefore the authentication method may not even be password-based.

I presume you want to do automatic authentication, in that case you can use key-based ssh. Github has [an example](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) how to do that.
If you're rolling your own Git server, then you need to add your key fingerprint to the `authorized_keys`, see the relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically?rq=1).