# Unable to connect to network and find eth0 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, nic

I have a ubuntu 14.04 running in my VmWare virtual machine and I unable to connect to internet from VM.I can't see eth0 in ifconfig in either bridged or NAT mode. The only setting I have is Network Adapter:NAT,Connected and Connect on Power on both are checked.

```
xyz@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:22628 (22.6 KB)  TX bytes:22628 (22.6 KB)

xyz@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:f0:87:76  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:22628 (22.6 KB)  TX bytes:22628 (22.6 KB)
```

Comment: What VM are you using?  VirtualBox?  VmWare?  Other?  In VirtualBox, you have settings to 1) Enable Network Adapter and 2) Cable Connected. Are both of those set correctly?

Comment: @Jonathan Iam using VmWare.The only setting I have is Network Adapter:NAT

Comment: I believe you should also have a checkbox for "Connect at power on".  Is that correct?  If so, is it checked?

Comment: Yes.Connected and Connect on Power on both are checked.

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/network/interfaces ?  Have you tried restarting the VM?

Comment: Yes I have restarted it multiple time with a hope of getting it to work.contents of interface file are                                                            "auto lo
iface lo inet loopback"

Comment: I have not made any changes to /interfaces and it was working before

Comment: Alright.I added "auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp" in /interfaces and now i can connect to internet.However I can't do ssh to a server that i was doing using my key,it says connection refused

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm placing the answer to your question in an answer rather than in the comments to make it easier to find for others finding this question via Google.

Check you /etc/network/interfaces file and make sure it includes the following two lines for eth0 (or your network interface)

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

For your question about ssh, check all the permission on both the client and server (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6377073/2263949), and check if you can ping it.  If you can ping, and permissions are OK but you still can't connect, check firewall settings.