# Ansible `authorized_key` copies the key to remote user but not working when trying to ssh

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have the following task in my ansible playbook that adds my ssh public key for a remote user `pranjal` that was already created by a previous task.

```
- authorized_key:
    user: pranjal
    key:  "{{ lookup('file', 'pranjal.pub') }}"
```

When I run the ansible playbook, it runs successfully. However when I try logging in to the server using: `ssh pranjal@<server_ip>`

I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

To be sure I logged into server from another user and double checked that key listed in `/home/pranjal/.ssh/authorized_keys` matches with my local public key that I am using to login.

The issue that I am guessing here could be a permissions issue and I understood the solution from a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically).

But how do we change permissions of authorized_key from within the Ansible task  itself? (So that I don't have to separately log into the instance to modify permissions of .ssh/authorized_keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- file: path=/home/pranjal/.ssh state=directory owner=pranjal mode=0700
- file: path=/home/pranjal/.ssh/authorized_keys state=file owner=pranjal mode=0600
```

You may also want to check/verify /etc/ssh/sshd_config has the following:

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

You can debug further by `ssh -vvv pranjal@<server_ip>`

Comment: PubKeyAuthentication was already present. File permission changes was what I needed. It works now!
Secondly I noticed that just running playbook again didn't register the new file tasks on the same instance, I created new instance and the file tasks worked on that. (Not sure why this happened)